# Is it possible to prevent a device from using saved settings to connect to a duplicate SSID?

Tags: wireless-networking, ssid

What can be done to prevent a device from connecting to a new wireless network with settings saved for a *different* network that used the same SSID?

How would the user know this was the case?

Security issues?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by *How would the user know this was the case?* Are you asking *how would the user know their device was trying to connect to a different SSID using saved settings?* Or are you perhaps asking *how would the user know they had been **prevented** from connecting to a duplicate SSID with saved settings?*

Answer (score 1):

If a device has a saved wireless connection for a network with a certain name, for example *wirelessnetwork1*, then when that device next sees a wireless network with the *same network name*, it will attempt to connect using the previously saved profile and only succeed if the saved settings match the network's settings.

In this case the user would become aware of the situation by the fact he couldn't connect.

The most straightforward way to prevent this from occurring is to configure the wireless client device **not to connect automatically to the wireless network**.

Comment: FYI: this occured mostly on android users when they didn't bother to change their ESSIDs and cause duplicates everywhere using the ESSID 'Android AP' crashing on each other.

Comment: @ProtoAES256 Do you mean this was a problem Andriod users *creating wireless hotspots* with their mobile devices and repeatedly using the same SSIDs?

Comment: yes, as sometimes 2 android phones create a same hotspot using the same name but different password(same encryption algo).